# Java List Error (Out Of Bounds)

Tags: java

I am attempting to make an infinite world 2d game

source for the class is here:

```
package com.blazingkin.world;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.blazingkin.atrox.AtroxAdventrum;

public class World {

    public World(AtroxAdventrum aa){
        chunks = new LinkedList<List<Chunk>>();
    }

    public void setBlock(int x, int y, int newBlock){

    }

    public void setMetadata(int x, int y, int newMeta){

    }
    public int getBlock(int x, int y){
        try{
            Chunk c = chunks.get(x/64 - x%64).get(y/64 - y%64);
            return c.chunk[x%64][y%64];
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            try{
            Chunk c = new Chunk(y, x/64 - x%64, y/64 - y%64);
            chunks.get(x/64 - x%64).add(y/64 - y%64 - 1, c);
            return c.chunk[x%64][y%64]; 
        }catch(Exception e1){
            Chunk c = new Chunk(y, x/64 - x%64, y/64 - y%64);
            List<Chunk> newlist = new LinkedList<Chunk>();
            System.out.println(""+x+", "+y);
            for (int i = 0; i<y/64 - y%64; i++){
                newlist.add(i, new Chunk(y - (y/64 - y%64 - i), x/64 - x%64, y/64 - y%64 - (y/64 - y%64 - i)));
            }
            newlist.add(y/64 - y%64 - 1, c);
            for (int i = 0; i<x/64 - x%64; i++){
                newlist.add(i, new Chunk(x - (x/64 - x%64 - i), x/64 - x%64, x/64 - x%64 - (x/64 - x%64 - i)));
            }
            chunks.add(x/64 - 1 - x%64, null);

            return 0;
        }
        }




    }
    public int getMetadata(int x, int y){
        return 1;
    }



    public List<List<Chunk>> chunks;

}
```

However, when i attempt to run this code i get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 0
    at java.util.LinkedList.entry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.blazingkin.world.World.getBlock(World.java:41)
    at com.blazingkin.render.ScreenOutput.render(ScreenOutput.java:30)
    at com.blazingkin.atrox.AtroxAdventrum.draw(AtroxAdventrum.java:34)
    at com.blazingkin.atrox.Core.gameLoop(Core.java:60)
    at com.blazingkin.atrox.Core.run(Core.java:27)
    at com.blazingkin.atrox.AtroxAdventrum.main(AtroxAdventrum.java:14)

Any suggestions as to how i could fix this?

Comment: What part of the exception don't you understand? The size is 0. Why is your List 0? If you solve that then you will solve your problem.

Comment: Why is my list 0 and why can I not add a value to any index of the list? Isn't that supposed to be an advantage of Lists?

Comment: No you can't add a value to any index of an "empty" list. You need to initialize the list with values at every index. Then you can replace the value if you want. But you can only add values sequentially to initially fill up the list. If your List is a fixed size, then you could use an Array. Then you can add values to any index of the Array without first populating the entire Array.

Comment: Some people voted your question down, but I actually think it's a good question. People, be positive!

Comment: The problem is with your choice of data structure (LinkedList of List). You want to use a different approach (I have described one such approach in an answer below). Good luck.

Comment: @LloydOzymandiasForce, Its a bad question because the poster just dumped that stack trace with the code and expected us to debug the code for them. There was no specific question about that indicated the posted had attempted to do any problem solving on their own.

Comment: I think the broken code is the posters attempt at solving the problem. Unfortunately, the code didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LinkedList is not a good choice for what you are trying to do. First, attempting to access elements of LinkedList by index is bad (performs O(n) instead of O(1)).

Use:

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Chunk>> chunks = new HashMap<Integer,Map<Integer,Chunk>>();

private void setChunk(Integer x, Integer y, Chunk c) {
    if(chunks.get(x) == null) {
        chunks.put(x, new HashMap<Integer, Chunk>());
    }
    chunks.get(x).put(y, c);
}
private Chunk getChunk(Integer x, Integer y) {
    if(chunks.get(x) == null)
        return null;
    return chunks.get(x).get(y);
}
```

In your code, you can use setChunk(1238238, -12938123, new Chunk(...)) and it will key the chunk under the x and y coordinate. To retrieve the value, use getChunk(1238238, -12938123). If no chunk exists for a given x, y, null will be returned.

Comment: Excellent Answer, except I would revise it to use BigInteger instead of Integer.  blazingkin wants an infinite world that is not constrained by Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

Index: 23 Size: 0 tells the story. You're trying to access element 23 of an empty list.

Comment: The problem is I need to be able to make a world that is infinite (to overflow) and starts at any point

Comment: @blazingkin regardless of your motivation, the problem is as I stated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing

```
chunks = new LinkedList<List<Chunk>>();
```

with

```
chunks = new ArrayList<List<Chunk>>(RANGE);
```

where RANGE probably is 64 but I did not read the code carefully and you should figure that out for yourself.

Comment: That won't cure that exception.

Comment: This will not work because I'm trying to create an INFINITE world that will start at any point so I cant use range

Comment: You can not create an INFINITE world that relies on List.  You can only reference about Integer.MAX_VALUE chunks.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit of a design problem. You are trying to add an element to "chunks" at a position derived from a method parameter where "chunks" is a class level attribute. Any reason why you should add elements at a given position? Can you not just do `chunks.add(element)`. Also, I am unsure why you would want to add null to the list. Do you want to remove instead?

Comment: The reason I was adding null was because i was attempting to figure out if the problem was in the chunk instance, I get the same error if i add the chunk

Comment: sure. try adding the "chunk" without a position, so it will be added as the last element. Also, whats the newlist thing?